# Cell data is not printing inside the table box

Tags: tables

I am making a table in LaTeX Beamer using below given template.

[image]

I have total 11 columns in my table but last 3 columns are not falling inside the table box. Can please somebody help me out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.7\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[tabgris,tabularx={c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}, boxrule=0.5pt, title =Comparison of computed torque and thrust with experimental data for various meshes]
            S.no.& \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Mesh size (million points)} & \multicolumn{4}{c|} {Torque (Nm)} & \multicolumn{4}{c} {Thrust (N)} \\
                 & Coarse  & Fine &  Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) & Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) \\  \hline \hline
                1&  1.13   & 8.60 & 804.0 & 686.1 & 719.0 & -4.6 & 1157.0 & 1094.1 & 1123.0 & -2.6 \\ \hline
                2&          1.45 & 11.0 & 804.0 & 691.2 & 713.1 & -3.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.2 & 1115.1 & -2.2 \\ \hline
                3&          1.70 & 13.0 & 804.0 & 690.0 & 719.2 & -4.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.3 & 1120.3 & -2.6\\ \hline
                4&          1.90 & 14.6 & 804.0 & 676.1 & 701.3 & -3.6 & 1157.0 & 1076.0 & 1110.0 & -3.1 
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{adjustbox} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, extend your code sniped to small complete document, which we can compile and see your problem.

Comment: A complete code which begin with `\documentclass` and  end with `\end{document}` including packages.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Environment adjustbox undefined.`

Comment: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/tabgris' `

Comment: Sorry David. I missed "\usepackage{adjustbox}" and 'tabgris' gives  color (which you can see in posted picture) to the table .

Comment: Can you add the definition of 'tabgris' in your question.

Comment: for me tabgris just gives an error are you missing a definition?

Comment: My code runs even after removing 'tabgris' but I have same issue of cells. Please try "\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}, boxrule=0.5pt, title =Comparison of computed torque and thrust with experimental data for various meshes]"

Comment: you use `tabularx` with width `0.7\textwidth`, but you use column types `c`. Contents in them, except in the first row doesn't obey prescribed width and are far wider than table width.  consequently this part of table protrude out of width of the first row.

Comment: In addition to these answers, I would argue that you're making your table look nice at the expense of making it harder to understand the information.  Take a look at the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package, even if you don't actually use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, that table should appear on `beamer` transparencies ... i.e. that it is very limited with text width and used font size.

For limiting complete table width to `\textwidth`, *it is not enough to use `\tabularx`, you had to use it in proper way! You should use column types from `\tabularx` (`X`) and not from `tabular` (`l`, `c`, `r`, or `p{...}`*. Otherwise cells with wider contents will *not obey prescribed table width* and will cause that the table rows with such cells will protrude out of defined right table border and maybe also the text border (as happens in your case).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}% <-- improve appearance of column heads
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}% <-- main change
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
    \tiny
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={ C | *{9}{C|}C},% <-- main change 
                  boxrule=0.5pt, 
                  title = Comparison of computed torque and thrust 
                           with experimental data for various meshes]
    &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}C|} {Mesh size\newline (million points) } % <-- main change
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c|} {Torque (Nm)} 
                &   \multicolumn{4}{c} {Thrust (N)} \\
S. no. & Coarse  & Fine &  Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) & Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) \\  \hline \hline
1   &  1.13   & 8.60 & 804.0 & 686.1  & 719.0 & -4.6 & 1157.0 & 1094.1 & 1123.0 & -2.6 \\ \hline
2   &  1.45   & 11.0 & 804.0 & 691.2  & 713.1 & -3.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.2 & 1115.1 & -2.2 \\ \hline
3   &  1.70   & 13.0 & 804.0 & 690.0  & 719.2 & -4.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.3 & 1120.3 & -2.6 \\ \hline
4   &  1.90   & 14.6 & 804.0 & 676.1  & 701.3 & -3.6 & 1157.0 & 1076.0 & 1110.0 & -3.1
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In case, that the table can be wider than `\textwidth`, you can employ package `changepage` and locally increase `\textwidth`, for example for `4.4em`. In this case you can use bigger font size (`\scriptsize` instead of `\tiny`). MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}% <-- added
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{changepage}%<-- added 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.2em}{-2.2em}    
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={ c | *{9}{C|}C},% <--- main change
                  boxrule=0.5pt,
                  title = Comparison of computed torque and thrust
                           with experimental data for various meshes]
    &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}C|}{Mesh size\newline (million points) }% <--- main change
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c|} {Torque (Nm)}
                &   \multicolumn{4}{c} {Thrust (N)} \\
S. no. & Coarse  & Fine &  Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) & Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) \\  \hline \hline
1   &  1.13   & 8.60 & 804.0 & 686.1  & 719.0 & -4.6 & 1157.0 & 1094.1 & 1123.0 & -2.6 \\ \hline
2   &  1.45   & 11.0 & 804.0 & 691.2  & 713.1 & -3.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.2 & 1115.1 & -2.2 \\ \hline
3   &  1.70   & 13.0 & 804.0 & 690.0  & 719.2 & -4.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.3 & 1120.3 & -2.6 \\ \hline
4   &  1.90   & 14.6 & 804.0 & 676.1  & 701.3 & -3.6 & 1157.0 & 1076.0 & 1110.0 & -3.1
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I do get a table but I am getting error messages saying "illegal parameter number in definition of \test. \end {tcolorbox} and illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end {frame}

Comment: I test both mine MWEs (again) as they in answer and I didn't got any error. I receive two warnings regarding font size/substitution.  I use MikTeX with recent upgrade. Error at you can arise due to differences in used package versions or you change MWE some how.

Comment: I also test answer of Salim Bou without any clash between packages. This some how confirm, that you probably use outdated packages. Now I also observe, that in your question you talk about `beamer`, but MWE use `article`.  Which `\documentclass` you really use?

Comment: If my answer fulfill your expectation and solve your problem successfully, you can accept it with click on check mark on the top left side of answer :-). or do this to another answer, if you estimate that better suited to your needs. Anyway, please explain, why the provided answer(s) work now. This can be valuable information to other members/users of this site.

Comment: @LatexUser, I improve/extend my answer with explanation what cause your problem and how to  proper use `tabularx`.

Answer (score 1):

Your table can't fit inside the colorbox, you can reduce font size and `\tabcolsep` which control inter column space

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\tcbuselibrary{skins} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % inter columns space 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}, boxrule=0.5pt, title =Comparison of computed torque and thrust with experimental data for various meshes]
            S.no.& \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Mesh size (million points)} & \multicolumn{4}{c|} {Torque (Nm)} & \multicolumn{4}{c} {Thrust (N)} \\
                 & Coarse  & Fine &  Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) & Exp. & Coarse & Fine & Diff*(\%) \\  \hline \hline
                1&  1.13   & 8.60 & 804.0 & 686.1 & 719.0 & -4.6 & 1157.0 & 1094.1 & 1123.0 & -2.6 \\ \hline
                2&          1.45 & 11.0 & 804.0 & 691.2 & 713.1 & -3.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.2 & 1115.1 & -2.2 \\ \hline
                3&          1.70 & 13.0 & 804.0 & 690.0 & 719.2 & -4.0 & 1157.0 & 1091.3 & 1120.3 & -2.6\\ \hline
                4&          1.90 & 14.6 & 804.0 & 676.1 & 701.3 & -3.6 & 1157.0 & 1076.0 & 1110.0 & -3.1 
        \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{scriptsize}   

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]